# Voltaje Sensor de Luz Assembler

Tags: arduino, nasm

Estoy realizando un proyecto de domotica con un arduino UNO y debo utilizar un sensor de luz, sin embargo ya que en ensamblador no existe la función analogRead() debo programarla, ya me lei la documentación de avr y atmel sobre el ADC, el MUX y su selección pero no me queda claro como es que se programa esto o como funciona, me vendría bien una explicación del siguiente código que me pasó un compañero el cual me afirma que los valores de cierto PIN quedan almacenados en ADCL y ADCH, mi pregunta es si alguien seria tan amable de explicarme el código y lo que está sucediendo en el ADC MUX. Es un 328p:

```
.equ F_CPU = 16000000;
.DEF rmp = R16 
.DEF tmp = R17
.DEF tmp2 = R18
.DEF reg1 = r20 
.DEF reg2 = r21
.EQU ALFA=250
.DSEG
.ORG  0X0100
.CSEG

.ORG $0000

jmp Main 

Main:

ldi rmp, HIGH(RAMEND) ; Init MSB stack
out SPH,rmp
ldi rmp, LOW(RAMEND) ; Init LSB stack
out SPL,rmp
; Init Port B
ldi rmp,0xff ; DIRECCION DEL Port B
out DDRB,rmp
rcall ad ; Call ADC Initialization
; [Add all other init routines here]
ldi rmp,1<<SE ; 
out MCUCR,rmp
sei 

Loop:

rcall adcRead
out PORTB,r18
rjmp loop ; go back to loop

ad: 

ldi rmp, (1<<REFS0) 
sts ADMUX, rmp 
ldi rmp, (1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0)
sts ADCSRA, rmp 
ret 

adcRead: 

lds rmp, ADCSRA    
ori rmp, (1<<ADSC) 
sts ADCSRA, rmp    

loopx:

lds  rmp, ADCSRA
sbrc rmp,ADSC
rjmp loopx     
lds r17,ADCL 
lds r18,ADCH 
ret
```

Comment: En el título pones assembler, en las etiquetas pones tres lenguajes. No entiendo nada. ¿En qué lenguaje estás programando?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus al menos está claro que no es ni python ni javascript ni tampoco C++ :S

Comment: Perdón por las etiquetas es ensamblador de ATMEL studio